# JPQL 2.0 - query entities based on superclass entity field

Tags: jpa-2.0, eclipselink, jpql, polymorphism

I have Entity (not MappedSuperclass) **Person** (with id, name, surname).
I also have Entity **Employee extends Person** (with other attributes, unimportant).
Inheritance Strategy is single table.

Now I want to create a namedQuery like this:

```
SELECT emp FROM Employee emp WHERE emp.name = ?1
```

In the IDE I get:

> the state field path emp.name cannot be resolved to a valid type

I think the problem is that the attribute belongs to the superclass entity.
So far, I haven't found any solution other than using the TYPE operator to perform a selective query on Employee instances.

I'd like to perform the query above. Is that possible?

I'm on EclipseLink/JPA 2.0

Comment: Pls post the Person and Employee classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JPQL seems valid.  Did you try it at runtime?  It could just be an issue with your IDE.

(include your code)

Comment: Indeed it was a Netbeans problem, I went on to deployment and it worked smoothly. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

`Person` has to be `@MappedSuperclass`.

http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/MappedSuperclass

Furthermore, you should use named parameters, e.g. `:name` instead of `?`...

Comment: if Person is an entity, it doesn't need to be a MappedSuperclass.